# How do I configure textpad to compile and run c++ programs in the windows command prompt?

Tags: c++, configure, textpad

I installed MinGW and was able to compile my c++ program in the windows command prompt and run it successfully. Now I am just wondering how I set up textpad to do that. I basically just need to know how to set up the tools in textpad, like i did when setting it up to work with java. Im not sure how to set the parameters, initial folder, regular expression, and registers?

Comment: I'd seriously recommend a decent IDE for c++ programming (e.g. Eclipse CDT). Building and debugging c++ programs is very different from _'working with java'_!